# PHP - Checking return value in an if statement

Tags: php

I have seen programming practices where a string or a boolean can be returned from a function. In such cases, is it recommended to check for empty() and isset() in the if loops, or will just doing a check like if($returnvar) will work or not.

Here's a piece of code I am playing around with. What do you think should be the output and are the checks correct in the if condition?

Thanks,

```
<?php

function testMe()
{
 try
 {
  $returnText = 'John King Rocks';
  return $returnText;
 }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
  return false;
 }
}

$str = testMe();
if ($str)
{
  echo $str;
}

?>
```

Comment: Note, the `return false;` here is unreachable -- nothing in the `try` block will cause an exception.

Comment: true.. but it's just an example, incase the code reaches there..

Comment: empty() can blow up on you - it thinks `'0'` is empty. don't use it unless you know exactly what you're going to be using it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work (for this specific example of `$str`), but checking for Boolean in PHP is risky, as you suggested, and should be done with caution, I would suggest (in general) to check it as follows:

```
if ($str !== false)
{
  echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What will happen is `$str` will be [type casted to a boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). So, the string will evaluate to `false` when it is:

1. The empty string
2. The string "0"

Every other value is considered `true`, which may not be the behavior you desire. So, to answer your questions:

> What do you think should be the output?

Well, the return string doesn't match either of the two conditions, so the `if` statement will evaluate to `true` and the `$str` will be `echo()`'d. (Not to mention that the above code can never produce an Exception).

> Are the checks correct in the if?

That depends on the functionality you're looking for. If you want to consider all strings (including "" and "0") to be valid, and to skip the `echo()` only when the function returns `false`, then you should check if the return value's equality with `!== false`. Otherwise, if those two conditions above are acceptable as `false`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is not a loop.  It's a conditional.  `echo false` will be coerced to `echo '0'`, so the `if` check is only necessary if you don't want to print a zero.  However, `echo null` will not print anything at all.  Even better would be to return empty string.  You should avoid mixing return types.  Many other languages don't even allow it.

By the way your exception handling does nothing .. the contents of the `try` cannot throw an exception.  Swallowing exceptions is also bad, and you need a `$` before the `e`.

In answer to your question, there is a phrase "paranoid programming is professional programming."  That is, you should do as many checks as possible if you want your application to work consistently (and the `if` check is good in this case), but it's also important to know what methods you are working with and the expected result.  Do you want some other handling if `testMe` is false?  Or do you want to just not print anything?

Comment: semantically, it's not a loop.  Conceptually, though, it could be considered a "loop" that runs 0 or 1 times.

Comment: @cHao I disagree.  A loop needs to have the ability to run an indefinite number of times.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Explain a `do {stuff} while(0)` "loop" then.  Or `for ($x=0; $x==0; ++$x)`.  These both run a definite number of times (one).  The keyword isn't important; a "loop" is just a condition + code to run when the condition's true, and can be made to run zero or one times.  When do we stop calling a loop a loop?

Comment: @cHao the keyword *is* important.  Can you run a function multiple times?  Do you call it a loop?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Yes, and no -- a function doesn't have a condition and always runs exactly once per call, so i don't consider it a loop.  If it's tail-recursive, that kinda blurs the lines...but still, no.

Comment: @cHao why do you want to overload the term "loop?"  If a non-developer or anyone asks you to write a program with a "loop that prints when x is 0" I guarantee you would write `while (x != 0)`, but you are telling me they might mean `if (x != 0)`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Yes, they could very well mean `if (x == 0) { print; }` rather than `while (x != 0) { do stuff; } print`.  And i don't care to overload the term -- i just want to make it clear that *conceptually*, `if` is just a degenerate loop.

Comment: @cHao your assertion that a loop requires a condition is also incorrect.  Even semantically, `goto` can produce a loop with no condition.  By your logic it seems that any part of a program can be considered a loop (or even the entire program itself).  What would be your definition of a loop exactly?

Comment: I, like you, consider a loop to be a marked section of code that is designed to run some (possibly infinite, probably multiple) number of times.  But i also see a conditional as a degenerate loop, in the same way a point is a degenerate circle.  I wouldn't call it a loop in normal usage, same as i wouldn't normally call a point a circle.  But conceptually, it is.